# tensorflow installation/usage problem under wsl - can't see GPU and libraries

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

Tried to install Tensorflow under WSL20 (Ubuntu) using pip.

installed automatically using pip install tensorflow, without any error messages.

When I am trying to run simple script like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))

print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

I got a large warning message:

```
2022-12-22 22:50:25.297540: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-12-22 22:50:25.409607: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:104] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2022-12-22 22:50:25.412608: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:25.412658: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-12-22 22:50:25.854668: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:25.854941: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:25.854964: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679236: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:967] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679366: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679425: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.11'; dlerror: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679460: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublasLt.so.11'; dlerror: libcublasLt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679496: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcufft.so.10'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679536: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcurand.so.10'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679571: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.11'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679609: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusparse.so.11'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679633: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-12-22 22:50:26.679640: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2022-12-22 22:50:26.680041: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
tf.Tensor(395.61298, shape=(), dtype=float32)
[]
```

So I can see that tf can't use some libraries and can't see GPU I have.

When I run  nvidia-smi to check if I have a driver for GPU it shows:

nvidia-smi
Thu Dec 22 22:35:48 2022

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.02    Driver Version: 526.98       CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P8     3W /  N/A |      0MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        29      G   /Xwayland                       N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What should I do to enable GPU for Tensorflow and  fix the situation with warnings?

Comment: Did you install the appropriate CUDA version? These are all CUDA libraries.

Comment: Do I need to install it before installing tensorflow? I see that nvidia-smi gives me some info in the right upper corner that I have CUDA version 12.0. How to check if it works fine?
I thought that tensorflow is dependent on that libraries so they must be installed as a dependency..  If not, what package or app should I install? Or how to check if they are installed or not? Maybe some manual/link?

Comment: I am trying to install latest CUDA version using provided instruction: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_network

Comment: No, nvidia-smi tells you the CUDA version supported by the driver, not the current CUDA installation, you have to install it.

Comment: Tried to install - using : sudo apt-get -y install cuda --fix-missing.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 default-jre-headless
 default-jre
 cuda-nsight-12-0
...
 cuda
...
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.16%2b8-0ubuntu1%7e22.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre_11.0.16%2b8-0ubuntu1%7e22.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: worked for me to update required packages: `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false -o Acquire::Check-Date=false update` but tensorflow doesn't see the libraries still.. How can I check if the CUDA is installed correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it will be useful for someone - just use this manual: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions

!be sure you install appropriate and compatible versions.

It worked when I have used: `cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0`

But when installed the newest versions and that was the problem - the tensorflow actually worked but it didn't detected any GPUs..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue installing TensorFlow/Keras in Ubuntu WSL for Windows 11 with NVIDIA GPU. This is how i resolved it.

1. Restart the whole process by following the instructions here,
   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2
2. running these in the Conda environment i created:
   pip install tensorflow-directml-plugin

here are my references to the solution:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2
https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin#tensorflow-directml-plugin-